# webservices healthcheck url and behaviour

Tags: rest, web-services, http, uri

*DISCLAIMER*: At first, It seemed to me like this is too simple question to ask, however I couldn't find any definitive answer and there is a chance the answer is out there in a community but not documented because it's too simple :}

The questions are:

- is there a canonic URL for healthcheck of a web service. If yes what is it.
- is there a common way of encoding the health information whether in body or return code...

(canonical in a sense most tools and platforms recognize it and support it natively)

Answer (score 1):

It is up to REST service developer how to implement health-check of their service. The main reason is that REST service is implementing certain business logic and different logic has different "attributes" of how healthy a service is.

Regarding encoding health information, the normal way is to provide response status code which is considered problematic if response is a kind of **5xx**, which means that server failed to fulfill the request.

Codes like **4xx** cannot be considered for healthchecking hence they rather mean that problem was caused by the client.

Alongside with status code they often supply error details in response body. Like:

`{status: "ERROR", description: "Here is error description"}`

**P.S.** - Some implementations extend the code range and introduce their own which are to be treated in a special way that is implied by service developers.